# User identity and microservices

Tags: microservices, session, login, oauth2, user-control

I have created a `User` service that controls user login using OAuth2 protocol and stores the user in the local database. So this service is aware of the user session and user identity.
Now I have another service `Foo` with some endpoint `/foo`. And the problem is that I need to know which user made the request to `/foo` endpoint. But the problem is that `Foo service` is unaware about the user and session.
What are the solutions and best practices for handling this scenario?

Comment: Why are they unaware? Once logged in, the user should have a token that says as much, which the Foo service can respect.

Comment: @Telastyn so should the Foo service have the duplicate logic for validating the token? For now, only the User service has this logic. If so, should both services share the same client-id and client-sercret or should each service have it's own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual approach is for the authentication service to issue the user a signed token. Other services can verify the signature to check that the token is genuine. The token then contains the user ID. Don't roll your own, but use an existing approach like JWT instead. Be aware of the drawbacks: tokens cannot be revoked individually. A token is valid until it expires, or until the signing key for all tokens is revoked.

In many cases such a zero-knowledge architecture is not necessary (well, the other services do at least have to know the public key for the token signature). Your services can talk to each other. There's no general reason why the foo-service shouldn't be able to ask the user service “is this token valid and which user does it represent?”.

Note that your internal services don't have to correspond 1:1 with externally visible endpoints. E.g. it would not be unusual to provide the API through a server that just translates the requests to various internal services. This frontend or facade is also a great place to add shared concerns like authentication. Your internal services would then be firewalled of from the public, and could assume that any provided user ID has already been authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It really clarifies a lot! So one approach is to have authentication in the API gateway service but storing users to DB in the user service, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)